# Why am I receiving the identity insert error even after explicitly setting IDENTITY_INSERT ON and using a column list?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, insert, table, identity

My code:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT SomeCoolDatabase.BoringOldSchema.TableWithIdentityColumn ON

INSERT INTO SomeCoolDatabase.BoringOldSchema.TableWithIdentityColumn
SELECT ColumnWithIdentity, OtherColumnWithoutIdentity, LastColumnInThisTable
FROM ALinkedServer.PrettyCoolDatabaseAsWell.StandardSchema.TableWithIdentityColumn

SET IDENTITY_INSERT SomeCoolDatabase.BoringOldSchema.TableWithIdentityColumn OFF
```

The error:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> An explicit value for the identity column in table
>   'SomeCoolDatabase.BoringOldSchema.TableWithIdentityColumn' can only be specified when a column list
>   is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a column list to your code:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT SomeCoolDatabase.BoringOldSchema.TableWithIdentityColumn ON

INSERT INTO SomeCoolDatabase.BoringOldSchema.TableWithIdentityColumn 
    (ColumnWithIdentity, OtherColumnWithoutIdentity, LastColumnInThisTable)
SELECT ColumnWithIdentity, OtherColumnWithoutIdentity, LastColumnInThisTable
FROM ALinkedServer.PrettyCoolDatabaseAsWell.StandardSchema.TableWithIdentityColumn

SET IDENTITY_INSERT SomeCoolDatabase.BoringOldSchema.TableWithIdentityColumn OFF

GO
```

Basically, a column list is when you explicitly state what columns you're inserting into.

Just remember that when you set [`IDENTITY_INSERT ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), you must specify in your insert statement the value for the column that is the identity
(in your case the column `ColumnWithIdentity`). 
If `IDENTITY_INSERT OFF`, SQL Server sets the first free value for the identity column, and so you must not add the `ColumnWithIdentity` field in the `SELECT` part of your `INSERT`.